# In Spark, RDDs are immutable, then how Accumulators are implemented?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, rdd

Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDDs) are designed to be immutable. One of the reasons behind making them immutable lies in fault tolerance and avoidance as they are handled by many processes and possibly many nodes at the same time. This can avoid race conditions and also avoid the overhead involved in trying to control those conditions.

There are a couple of illustrations as to how RDDs are implemented (E.g., [this one](http://www.gabormelli.com/RKB/Spark_RDD_Data_Structure)). However, I can't seem to find one that illustrates how an [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) is implemented. It *is* under the RDD section in the Apache Spark docs. 
Does this mean a new RDD is created for every increment in the value, or is it a different data structure altogether?

Answer (score 6):

`Accumulator` are write-only variables for executors.They can be added to by executors and read by the driver only.

```
executors and read by the driver only.
executor1: accumulator.add(incByExecutor1)
executor2: accumulator.add(incByExecutor2)

driver:  println(accumulator.value)
```

`Accumulators` are not thread-safe. They do not really have to since the [DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-dagscheduler.html#updateAccumulators) method that the driver uses to update the values of accumulators after a task completes (successfully or with a failure) is only executed on a single thread that runs scheduling loop. Beside that, they are write-only data structures for workers that have their own local accumulator reference whereas accessing the value of an accumulator is only allowed by the driver.
Accumulators are serializable so they can safely be referenced in the code executed in executors and then safely send over the wire for execution.

```
val counter = sc.longAccumulator("counter")
sc.parallelize(1 to 9).foreach(x => counter.add(x))
```